# Laravel Downloaded file from the browser gets corrupted

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to download the file saved in s3. So I have codes like below.

```
static public function download($key, $disk = 's3') : object
{

    $file = FileHelper::get($key);

    $local = Storage::disk('local');
    $local->put(basename($key), $file);
    $pathToFile = storage_path().'/app/'.basename($key);

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\mimetype_from_filename(basename($key)),
        'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
        'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=' ". basename($key),
        'filename'=> basename($key)
    ];

    $repsonse = response()->download($pathToFile, basename($key), $headers)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    ob_end_clean();

    return $repsonse;
}
```

And I have the javascript code like below.

```
downloadFile() {
            var app = this;

            var url = baseRoute + 'files/' + this.fileId + '/download';
            axios.get(url, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'bearer ' + this.Authentication.tokenData().token,
                    responseType : "blob"
                }
            }).then(function (response) {

                var today = ((new Date()).toISOString()).slice(2,10),
                    filename = today.replace(/-/gi, "")+' '+ app.fileTitle;

                let blob = new Blob([response.data], {
                    type: response.headers['content-type']
                });

                let link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = filename;
                link.click();

            }).catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
```

The file is downloaded, however, the file is corrupted. (it would not open) I checked S3 bucket to see if the file is corrupted during upload, but it was fine there.

What am I doing wrong? Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**Added: when I tried to view the image, it returned white squared which means its base64 encoded image. Does it have to do with being empty file?**

Comment: please first try to read the file content with an editor. in many cases, when the server you try to download may not accept your credentials and send an error response. if you are trying to download a zip file, you will get a "file.zip" with HTML content, and get an error if you try to open. if axios has it in, try to check if response is OK to continue.

Comment: Also, are you encrypting the file when writing it to the S3 bucket? If so, are you remembering to decrypt it when reading from the S3 bucket?

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz I have checked that response is 200(OK).

Comment: Its kinds weird that I tried xml file it works fine. But other files do not work.

Comment: @smchae, just as a caution, try to print the content you get, to the console after download, and once more before saving to disk, to see if content is get correctly from server, and it ok before writing.

Comment: only files with extension of `*.txt` and `*.xml`.

Comment: @fubar I do not encrypt the file

Comment: `'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename='". basename($key) ."'"` there is an apostrophe missing here, add it and try again. if this solves your problem, you can delete this question safely :))

Comment: may you please give a comment if the above suggestion fixed the problem? tag my name in the comment.

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz It did not work. However, I got it working by using `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: @smchae, nice, now that you have a solution, you can provide a working code as an answer and accept it, or delete the question itself. don't leave it like this

Answer (score 0):

I had to use standard `XMLHttpRequest` to work it like below.

```
downloadFile() {

            var app = this;
            var url = baseRoute + 'files/' + this.fileId + '/download';
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", url);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer ' + this.Authentication.tokenData().token);
            xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

            xhr.onload = function () {

                if (this.status === 200) {

                    var today = ((new Date()).toISOString()).slice(2,10),
                        filename = today.replace(/-/gi, "")+' '+ app.fileTitle;

                    var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type')});
                    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                    let link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = objectUrl;
                    link.download = filename;
                    link.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        },
```